# understanding and reporting results from monte-carlo simulation

Tags: data-visualization, simulation, monte-carlo, prediction-interval, reporting

I apologize upfront if the the question is vague. Basically I have results from monte carlo simulation and I'm trying to understand how to present the results and importantly the "why" part of the question. I attended a seminar on simulations and this question was from an exercise from that seminar. The instructor asked to run the following without any clear explanations:

1. Run 5,000 simulations and obtained prediction intervals for these simulations.
2. Repeat step 1: 50 different times report the results.

Below are my questions:

1. Why would you run it 50 different times ? why not run 50x5000 =
   25000 at single stretch ?
2. How to report the above results visually?
3. Should I be calculating prediction intervals for each of the 50 realizations and reporting it separately ?

I'm using `R` software for simulations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.